# Aplicativo Foursquare

Tags: php, javascript, app, token

Estou criando um aplicativo `foursquare`, porém não estou conseguindo usar o endpoint `users/request`. Queria enviar uma solicitação de amizade via `api`, sei que é possível por que o site [soubeta.com](http://soubeta.com) consegue fazer.

Pelo que percebi o problema está no token, o meu app pega o token via `api`, mas quando envio o `endpoint` não funciona, já quando uso um token gerado por esse site, o `endpoint` funciona.

Alguém sabe o porquê disso? No momento em que se cria o app no site do `foursquare` tem que especificar mais alguma coisa ?